# Extract BLOB Files from Database and save on file system

Tags: oracle, plsql

I need to migrate some documents from a CRM to a new CRM.  The documents (PDF, DOCx etc) are on the Oracle database within a BLOB column.

I have never had to deal with BLOBs in this way before so I'm a little lost.

What is the best way to extract the files from the BLOB column, in their original format, and save them to a local drive?

I've tried the code below, but I maybe don't have the correct permissions for it to run (or it's just not right)

```
DECLARE
  l_file      UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE;
  l_buffer    RAW(32767);
  l_amount    BINARY_INTEGER := 32767;
  l_pos       NUMBER := 1;
  l_blob      BLOB;
  l_blob_len  NUMBER;
BEGIN

  SELECT CONT_DATA
  INTO   l_blob
  FROM   FILE_CONT
  WHERE  rownum = 1;

  l_blob_len := DBMS_LOB.getlength(l_blob);

  -- Open the destination file.
  l_file := UTL_FILE.fopen('Z:\','test.pdf','wb', 32767);

  WHILE l_pos < l_blob_len LOOP
    DBMS_LOB.read(l_blob, l_amount, l_pos, l_buffer);
    UTL_FILE.put_raw(l_file, l_buffer, TRUE);
    l_pos := l_pos + l_amount;
  END LOOP;

  -- Close the file.
  UTL_FILE.fclose(l_file);

END;
```

Comment: [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49138474/5841306) might help.

Comment: At first glance, that looks ok. But you say it's not working. What error are you getting?

Comment: First thing that jumps out is that you can not just use Z:\ in your fopen statement. You will need to declare a directory object in oracle (https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_5007.htm) then use that.